# Computing minimal polynomials using LLL

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, algorithms, computational-number-theory

I would like to use the Lenstra–Lenstra–Lovász lattice basis reduction algorithm (LLL algorithm) to compute the minimal polynomial of a (real) algebraic number $\alpha$ from a decimal approximation $a$ (and bounds on its degree and height). A fairly standard idea for how to do this is to pick a large constant $N$ and apply the LLL algorithm to the lattice:
\begin{eqnarray}
&(1 \; 0 \; 0 \; \cdots \; 0 \; \lfloor N \rfloor),& \\
&(0 \; 1 \; 0 \; \cdots \; 0 \; \lfloor Na \rfloor),& \\ 
&(0 \; 0 \; 1 \; 0 \; \cdots \; 0 \; \lfloor Na^2 \rfloor),& \\
&\vdots& \\
&(0 \; \cdots \; 0 \; 1 \; \; \lfloor Na^d \rfloor)& \\
\end{eqnarray}
The first vector of the basis returned by the LLL algorithm is
$$ \left(a_0 \; a_1 \; \cdots \; a_d \; N \sum a_i a^i \right) $$
As all of these entries are small, we obtain a small integer relation between $a^0, \ldots, a^d$. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm#Applications) for an example of doing this to compute a quadratic that has a root close to $1.618034$ using $N = 10000$. However this process depends on the choice of $N$. Too small will result in underfitting while too large will result in overfitting.

> Is there an explicit procedure for determining what value of $N$ to use (as a function of the bounds on the degree and height of $\alpha$)?

Most of the papers that I have looked which discuss this approach at appear to use a fairly ad-hoc method. The only place where I could find choosing $N$ being addressed is Cohen (A course in computational algebraic number theory, Section 2.7.2) where he says that:

> ``The choice of the constant $N$ is subtle, and depends in part on what one knows
>   about the problem. If the $|a^i|$ are not too far from 1 (meaning between $10^{-6}$ and $10^6$ , say), and are known with an absolute (or relative) precision $\epsilon$, then one should take $N$ between $1 / \epsilon$ and $1 / \epsilon^2$, but $\epsilon$ should also be taken quite small: if one expects the coefficients $a_i$; to be of to be of the order of $x$, then one might take $\epsilon = x^{1.5d}$, but in any case $\epsilon < x^{-d}$.''

[I've modified the variable names to match the previous section.]

Comment: PARI-GP has a built-in function called algdep(x,d) that uses LLL to compute an integer polynomial of degree d with f(x) very small. I realize you didn't ask for a package, but the source code for PARI is public, so it should be possible to check how PARI uses LLL. And in particular, since Henri Cohen was quite active with PARI, it's likely that the implementation is a practical version of the comment you quote from his book.

Comment: Umm, what's the question? Do you want something more than what Cohen says?

Comment: @Igor: I guess I have two questions: 1) What exactly does Cohen mean by "subtle"? 2) Have there been any further developments in how to choose $N$ in the 20 years since Cohen's book?

Comment: @JoeSilverman: Thanks for the suggestion. I've only had a brief chance to look at PARI but the relevant code appears to be "lindep2" in ./basemath/bibli1.c (the precision to work to (equiv. the choice of $N$) is chosen here not in algdep0). It appears that if the binary expansion of $a$ has $i$ bits before the decimal and $j$ bits afterwards then PARI uses $N = 10^{32+i}$ if $j = 0$ and $N = 10^{0.8 j}$ otherwise (or a user given precision).

Comment: @JoeSilverman: I should also add that the PARI documentation for algdep says that "the polynomial which is obtained is not necessarily the "correct" one". However its code requests a 0.99---LLL Reduced Basis using ZM_lll. With $\delta=0.99$ being so close to 1, we get "better guarantees for the basis (in principle smaller basis vectors) but longer running times".

Comment: @MarkBell You're welcome. In principle, there can't be a "correct" polynomial, since you're using a decimal approximation $\alpha$ to your algebraic number. And $\alpha$ is the root of many polynomials with integer coefficients. Of course, one wants the coefficients to be small in an appropriate sense. Anyway, it sounds as if the way PARI chooses $N$ is fairly *ad hoc*. So could be an interesting research project to find/prove something more precise.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Yes but shouldn't the bounds on the degree and height of $\alpha$ mean that $a$ determines a unique algebraic number, and so a unique polynomial? Perhaps a more basic question would be: is it true that $|a_i| \leq N$ (or some similar bound)?

Comment: @MarkBell If you know *a priori* that $\alpha$ is algebraic and you have a bound on its degree and height, then that should enable you to find the unique minimal polynomial having integer coefficients and positive leading coefficient, provided you know $\alpha$ to enough decimal places relative to the degree and height bound. OTOH, the bounds need not determine a unique polynomial with $\alpha$ as a root. For example, suppose $\alpha=\sqrt2$ (to some large precision) and your height bound is 2 and degree bound is 3. Then you might find $x^3-x^2-2x+2$ instead of $x^2-2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theory of "layered lattices" is an attempt to deal
with these issues. The 2011 thesis of Lenstra's student 
Erwin Dassen is devoted to this subject:

https://openaccess.leidenuniv.nl/handle/1887/18264

Answer (score 2):

This does not quite answer the question as posed, but Xiaolin Qin, Yong Feng, Jingwei Chen, Jingzhong Zhang claim a better [than LLL] algorithm (with all the parameters specified) to find integer relations (and thus to find the miminal polynomial) in [their 2010 paper.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0649) The paper is not written in the best English, but seems good otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that this question was also [asked on the cstheory stackexchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19882/factoring-with-lll-when-the-form-of-the-factors-is-given). They reference chapter 9 of C. Yap's "Fundamental Problems in Algorithmic Algebra" where this exact problem is tackled. In this, he shows that taking $N = 2^{4 h^3}$ is sufficient where $h$ is the height of $\alpha$.

Answer (score -1):

A funny instance. Let $r=3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097\cdots$ -the $120$ first significant digits of $\pi$-. With lll, we obtain  polynomials (with integer coefficients) of degrees $19$ and $34$. Thus if we only know that $r$ is algebraic with degree $\leq 34$, then we cannot conclude without the knowledge of supplementary digits.